# the label is repeating itself while scrolling

Tags: ios

I am having a screen in which I am having a UIScrollView. A UITableView is embedded in that. The problem which I am suffering is of Cell reuse. I am attaching a few screenshots here for the problem clarification.

Before scrolling: As the screen loads.

[image]

While Scrolling:

[image]

and then scrolling back upwards:

[image]

as you can see due to the cell reuse the LBM is now shown in place of the date. Since this is a built in group table cell, I am not able to use the prepForReuse.

I am attaching my code for the cellForRowAtIndexPath here.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView 
     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 
      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        // Here we are creating Custom Label to Display the TakenTime and TakenDate of Vitals
        // in center.
        if (indexPath.row==0) {
            lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, 320, 33)];
            lbl_title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            lbl_title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
            lbl_title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            lbl_title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_title];
        }

    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            lbl_title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dic_vitalsDictonary 
        valueForKey:@"taken_date"],[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"taken_time"]];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Height";
            NSString * str_height = [[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"height"]  floatValue] 
            > 0 ? [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"height"] : @"";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self setDecimalFormatForString:str_height];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Weight";
            NSString * str_weight = [[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"weight"] floatValue] >
            0 ? [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"weight"] : @"";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self setDecimalFormatForString:str_weight];
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Temperature";
            NSString * str_temprature = [[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"temp"] floatValue]
             > 0 ? [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"temp"] : @"";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self setDecimalFormatForString:str_temprature];
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Blood Pressure";
            NSString * str_lowbp = [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"lowbp"];
            NSString * str_highbp = [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"highbp"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[self
            setDecimalFormatForString:str_lowbp],[self setDecimalFormatForString:str_highbp]];
            break;
        case 5:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Blood Sugar";
            NSString * str_bs1 = [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"bs_1"];
            NSString * str_bs2 = [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"bs_2"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[self 
            setDecimalFormatForString:str_bs1],[self setDecimalFormatForString:str_bs2]];
            break;
        case 6:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Pulse";
            NSString * str_pulse = [[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"pulse"] floatValue] > 0
            ? [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"pulse"] : @"";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self setDecimalFormatForString:str_pulse];
            break;
        case 7:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Resp";
            NSString * str_resp = [[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"resp"] floatValue] > 0 ?
            [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"resp"] : @"";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self setDecimalFormatForString:str_resp];
            break;
        case 8:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Oxygen";
            NSString * str_oxyzen = [[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"oxygen"] floatValue] >
            0 ? [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"oxygen"] : @"";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self setDecimalFormatForString:str_oxyzen];
            break;
        case 9:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Fatmass";
            NSString * str_fatmass = [[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"fatmass"] floatValue]
            > 0 ? [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"fatmass"] : @"";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self setDecimalFormatForString:str_fatmass];
            break;
        case 10:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"LBM";
            NSString * str_lbm = [[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"lbm"] floatValue] > 0 ?
            [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"lbm"] : @"";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self setDecimalFormatForString:str_lbm];
            break;
        case 11:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"HC";
            NSString * str_hc = [[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"hc"] floatValue] > 0 ? 
            [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"hc"] : @"";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self setDecimalFormatForString:str_hc];
            break;
        case 12:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Peakflow";
            NSString * str_peakflow = [[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"peakflow"] 
            floatValue] > 0 ? [dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"peakflow"] : @"";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text =[self setDecimalFormatForString:str_peakflow];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Set the Background Image for TableviewCell.
    // if 1st row then we are showing different image to Display Vitals Date.

    if (indexPath.row==0) {

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage 
        imageNamed:@"HeaderNavigation.png"]];
    }
    else{
        // Set the Background Image for TableviewCell.
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage
         imageNamed:@"cell_background.png"]];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;

}
```

Please suggest some way to get over this scenario. I have tried a lot but nothing seems to work in the way I intend. I want to prevent the cell from being reused so that it does not repeat itself during scrolling.

Comment: lbl_title is only used in row 0 right?

Comment: This is happening because only first time cell is allocated and you are reusing cell, which means when scrolled down cell at zero will be taken by the other cell and it will display its text depending on its indexpath. So one easy way is take different cell identifier for first cell so and other cell identifier for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try and give a unique identifier for every cell,

```
 NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:"Cell %d",indexpath.row];
```

dont know if this is the right way, but it should solve ur problem.

Comment: This is not correct as you are not reusing the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `cell.textLabel.hidden = NO;` before the switch statement and then hide it for the first row:

```
 case 0:
    cell.textLabel.hidden = YES; //this is added
    lbl_title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dic_vitalsDictonary 
    valueForKey:@"taken_date"],[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"taken_time"]];
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two changes: Add a tag to `lbl_title` and remove the subview with that tag whenever reusing and hide the `textLabel` when creating cell for first row. Alternatively, use a different cell identifier for the first row since that cell is different from the rest.

EDIT: There are several examples already available on how to do this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView 
     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 
      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];    
    }

    UILabel *lbl_title = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 'lblt'];
    lbl_title.hidden = YES; 

    cell.textLabel.hidden = NO;

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
        // Here we are creating Custom Label to Display the TakenTime and TakenDate of Vitals
        // in center.
            if (lbl_title == nil)
            {
                lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, 320, 33)];
                lbl_title.tag = 'lblt';
                lbl_title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                lbl_title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
                lbl_title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                lbl_title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_title];
            }
            lbl_title.hidden = NO;
            cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;
            lbl_title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dic_vitalsDictonary 
        valueForKey:@"taken_date"],[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"taken_time"]];
            break;
        case 1:
```

Alternatively,

Simply change `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` to `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: (indexPath.row == 0 ? CellIdentifier2 : CellIdentifier)];` since the first row uses a different type of cell.

Comment: can u show how to implement your first case through code. I am not getting the removing the subview part and hiding it simultaneously.

Comment: @Shikhar the answer you selected is not the right way of doing it. Take a look at my updated answer that has the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are configuring your title label if cell==nil condition.
It will not execute everytime.So use below code to fullfill your requirement.You do not need to declare title label as globle.

```
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    // Here we are creating Custom Label to Display the TakenTime and TakenDate of Vitals
    // in center.
    UILabel *lbl_title= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, 320, 33)];
    lbl_title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl_title.tag=21;
    lbl_title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    lbl_title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl_title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell addSubview:lbl_title];
}

if (indexPath.row==0) {
    UILabel *titleLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:21];
    titleLabel.text=@"May 1 ,2013 17:23:49";
}else{
    UILabel *titleLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:21];
    titleLabel.text=@"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
 if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 
  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    // Here we are creating Custom Label to Display the TakenTime and TakenDate of Vitals
    // in center.

        UILabel *topLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, 320, 33)];
        topLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
       topLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
       topLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       topLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       topLabel.tag = 1;// unique for all subviews of cell
       [cell.contentView addSubview:topLabel];

 }
  topLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
  topLabel.text = nil;
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
  cell.textLabel.text = nil;
  switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0: 

        topLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dic_vitalsDictonary 
    valueForKey:@"taken_date"],[dic_vitalsDictonary valueForKey:@"taken_time"]];
        break;
  //OTHER CODE
```

Comment: hey shikhar can you check again? didn't use lbl_title but instead a new instance of label which doesn't exist globally

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove label while scrolling to reuse it. So use these lines of coding:

```
 if (cell == nil)
{

    // your code for adding label and set tag as 99
}
else
{ 
     UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:99];
     [label removeFromSuperview];
     label = nil;
}
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: Do I have to remove the if(indexPath.row == 0) condition in the if(cell == nil) condition while adding my label. As your code is not working in the way you have stated here.

Answer (score -1):

if you dont want to **reuse** cell then update this code

```
UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView 
 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 
  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    // Here we are creating Custom Label to Display the TakenTime and TakenDate of Vitals
    // in center.
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, 320, 33)];
        lbl_title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lbl_title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        lbl_title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lbl_title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_title];
    }

}
```

with this

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 
  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    // Here we are creating Custom Label to Display the TakenTime and TakenDate of Vitals
    // in center.
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, 320, 33)];
        lbl_title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lbl_title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        lbl_title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lbl_title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_title];
    }
```